# Check and Update multiple attributes of AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to do an update to Active Directory from a CSV.
I want to check each value to see if the AD and CSV values match.
If the AD value and CSV values don't match, then I want to update the AD value.
finally I want to create a log of the values changed, which would eventually be exported to a CSV report.

Now there is about 30 values I want to check.
I could do an if statement for each value, but that seems like the hard way to do it.

I am try to use a function, but I cant seem to get it working.
I am getting errors like:

```
set-ADUser : replace
At line:94 char:9
+         set-ADUser -identity $ADUser -replace @{$ADValue = $DIAccount ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (JDoe:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: Surname
At line:94 char:9
+         set-ADUser -identity $ADUser -replace @{$ADValue = $DIAccount ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (JDoe:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Any suggestions would be welcome
Code I am using:

```
Function AD-Check ($ADValue, $ADUser, $ADAccount, $UpdateAccount)
{
    If ($ADAccount -ne $UpdateAccount)
    {
        set-ADUser -identity $ADUser -replace @{$ADValue = $UpdateAccount}
        $Change = "Updated"
    }
    Else
    {
        $Change = "No Change"
    }
 
    Return $Change
}

$Import = get-content C:\temp\ADUpdates.csv

Foreach ($user in $Import)
{
    $Account = get-aduser $User.Samaccountname -Properties *

    #First Name Check
    $Test = AD-Check "GivenName" $Account.samaccountname $Account.givenname $user.givenname
    $ChangeGivenName = $Test

    #Initials Check
    $Test = AD-Check "Initials" $Account.samaccountname $Account.Initials $user.Initials
    $ChangeInitials = $Test

    #Last Name Check
    $Test = AD-Check "Surname" $Account.samaccountname $Account.SurnameSurname $user.Surname
    $ChangeSurname = $Test
}
```

Reply to Theo, cant seem to add this any other way...

Thanks Theo, it seems to make sense, but getting an error.

```
Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection to one of the following types {System.String, 
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
```

changed the following to get all properties for testing and it works.

```
$Account = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$sam'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Properties $propsToCheck
```

Left the following and it kicks the error

```
$oldProperties = $Account | Select-Object $propsToCheck
```

Using the following just for testing:

```
$propertiesMap = [ordered]@{
    SamAccountName = 'sAMAccountName'
    mail           = 'mail'
    GivenName      = 'givenName'
    Initials       = 'initials'
    Surname        = 'sn'
    Office         = 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    MobilePhone    = 'mobile'
    DistinguishedName = 'DistinguishedName'
}
```

Comment: You can do a `switch` statement

Comment: The best way to go would be to use the Compare-Object function for each line

Comment: The LDAP display name for the Surname attribute is `sn`, not `Surname`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is correct. When using the `-Replace @{name = Value }` method on Set-ADUser, you need to use the correct LDAP attribute names (in the correct casing). [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx) may help you with that. Also I'd recommend putting the `Set-ADUser` stuff in your function inside `try{}..catch{..}` blocks and **refresh** the data after setting with a Get-ADUser to know if the setting changed or not.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. Changed the declaration of `$propsToCheck` into `$propsToCheck = $propertiesMap.Keys | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString() }`

Answer (score 0):

### Starting of with a WARNING:

> Replacing user attributes is not something to be taken lightly and you
> need to check any code that does that on a set of testusers first.
> Keep the `-WhatIf` switch to the Set-ADUser cmdlet so you
> can first run this without causing any problems to the AD.
> Only once you are satisfied all goes according to plan, remove the `-WhatIf` switch.
>
> Please carefully read all inline comments in the code.

In your code you use an input CSV file, apparently with properties and values to be checked/updated, but instead of using `Import-Csv`, you do a `Get-Content` on it, so you'll end up with just lines of text, not an array of parsed properties and values..

Next, as [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528837/check-and-update-multiple-attributes-of-ad-users#comment119361853_67528837) already commented, you need to use the LDAP attribute names when using either the `-Add`, `-Remove`, `-Replace`, or `-Clear` parameters of the Set-ADUser cmdlet.

To do what you intend to do, I would first create a hashtable to map the PowerShell attribute names to their LDAP equivalents.
To see which property name maps to what LDAP name, you can use the table [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

```
# create a Hashtable to map the properties you want checked/updated
# the Keys are the PowerShell property names as they should appear in the CSV
# the Values are the LDAP AD attribute names in correct casing.
$propertiesMap = [ordered]@{
    SamAccountName = 'sAMAccountName'
    GivenName      = 'givenName'
    Initials       = 'initials'
    Surname        = 'sn'
    Office         = 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    Organization   = 'o'
    MobilePhone    = 'mobile'
    # etcetera
}

# for convenience, store the properties in a string array
$propsToCheck = $propertiesMap.Keys | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString() }

# import your CSV file that has all the properties you need checked/updated
$Import = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\ADUpdates.csv'

# loop through all items in the CSV and collect the outputted old and new values in variable $result
$result = foreach ($user in $Import) {
    $sam = $user.SamAccountName
    # try and find the user by its SamAccountName and retrieve the properties you really want (not ALL)
    $Account = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$sam'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Properties $propsToCheck
    if (!$Account) {
        Write-Warning "A user with SamAccountName '$sam' does not exist"
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next user from the CSV
    }
    # keep an object with the current account properties for later logging
    $oldProperties = $Account | Select-Object $propsToCheck

    # test all the properties and create a Hashtable for the ones that need changing
    $replaceHash = @{}
    foreach ($prop in $propsToCheck) {
        if ($Account.$prop -ne $user.$prop) {
            $ldapAttribute = $propertiesMap[$prop]       # get the LDAP name from the $propertiesMap Hash
            # If any of the properties have a null or empty value Set-ADUser will return an error.
            if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($($user.$prop))) {
                $replaceHash[$ldapAttribute] = $user.$prop
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "Cannot use '-Replace' with empty value for property '$prop'"
            }
        }
    }

    if ($replaceHash.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "User '$sam' does not need updating"
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next user from the CSV
    }

    # try and do the replacements
    try {
        ##########################################################################################################
        # for safety, I have added a `-WhatIf` switch, so this wll only show what would happen if the cmdlet runs. 
        # No real action is performed when using '-WhatIf'
        # Obviously, there won't be any difference between the 'OLD_' and 'NEW_' values then
        ##########################################################################################################
        $Account | Set-ADUser -Replace $replaceHash -WhatIf
        # refresh the account data
        $Account = Get-ADUser -Identity $Account.DistinguishedName -Properties $propsToCheck
        $newProperties = $Account | Select-Object $propsToCheck
        # create a Hashtable with the old and new values for log output
        $changes = [ordered]@{}
        foreach ($prop in $propsToCheck) {
            $changes["OLD_$property"] = $oldProperties.$prop
            $changes["NEW_$property"] = $newProperties.$prop
        }
        # output this as object to be collected in variable $result
        [PsCustomObject]$changes
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Error changing properties on user '$sam':`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# save the result as CSV file so you can open with Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\ADUpdates_Result.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Tried this, and still getting an error. Updated question with results.

Comment: @Kel I see what you mean... I just redid the declaration of `$propsToCheck` to ensure it's a string array. Also, please use the proper LDAP casing in the `$propertiesMap`: `DistinguishedName = 'distinguishedName'` (lowercase 'd' for LDAP)